# Unable to resolve dependency for ':feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve Gradle Plugin 3.3

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm developing app with multiple [dynamic feature module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery). But when I tried to update gradle plugin to version `3.3.2` it always fail.

With a lot of error message like this `ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':feature_name@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve ...` or `ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':feature_name@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve ...`

It works fine with gradle plugin `3.2.1`.

This is my gradle plugin in my project `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:1.11'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
}
```

I use gradle wrapper 4.10.2 `gradle-wrapper.properties`

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`

This is my feature `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion builds.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion builds.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode builds.versionCode
        versionName builds.versionName
        minSdkVersion builds.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion builds.compileSdk
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.11'

    // lifecycle
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0'

    implementation project(':app')
    implementation project(':lib_component')
}
```

I've tried `clean` project, `invalidate caches & restart`, and delete `.idea` and `.gradle` directory, and also, **Offline Work** already **unchecked**. The errors still happen.
[image: not offline].

What can I do to update my gradle plugin version?